# Displaying Column Description on Hover

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I would like to display the column description of my sharepoint list when the user hovers the mouse over the column header. Currently there is no out of the box solution for this and I followed this [guide](http://spjsblog.com/2012/05/15/show-field-description-in-list-view-column-header-updated-version/). However this guide does not work for SharePoint 2013. Any help or direction would be helpful!

Here is the list view that I am trying to apply this to.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The exact steps depend on if you plan to use a Content Editor web part or directly edit the View page. Let me know if you aren't sure how to do either.

The result:

[image: Column headings in mouseover]

The JavaScript:

Notes: Use the jQuery library version of your choice. Change the "Tickets" list name to your list name.

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
var testresults
function test() {
  var headings = document.getElementsByClassName('ms-vh-div')
  for (var i=0;i<headings.length; i++)
  {
    var columnName = headings[i].getAttribute("name");
    columnName = columnName.replace("_x0020_"," ");
    var head = headings[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
    //head.title = head.title + "\nhello world"

    $.ajax({
      "url": _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + 
             "/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('Tickets')/fields?$select=Description&$filter=Title eq '" + columnName + "'",
      "method": "GET" ,
      "theHeading": head,
      "headers": {
          "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
      },
      "success" : function(data) { 
        var xml = arguments[2].response; 
        var description = "" + $(xml).find("content").text()   
        this.theHeading.title += "\n" + description;
      },
      "error" : function(e) { console.log("error " + e.message) }
    });
  }
}

// delay script until SharePoint "stuff" is finished.
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("test")
</script>
```

Comment: I planned to do a content editor. This is very helpful though, so thank you!

Comment: Okay, I tried getting this to work. I inserted a Script editor into the page and changed the list to the list I want to use, but nothing changed. When I hover over the columns it says the list name and whether or not the column can be filtered upon. Any thoughts?

Comment: A couple of things to try: Use the browser's F12 tools, click the Console tab and see if there are any errors related to this code. Also with the F12 tools, search the DOM to see if the JavaScript code (for example, search for "var headings") is there, and unaltered. Start over and save the JavaScript in a text file (.txt or .html) and store in Site Assets, add a Content Editor web part, edit its properties and link to that file.

Comment: I did that and I am getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" on the javascript file

Comment: And also when I place the code in a script editor directly, I get the error "cannot read property 'title' of undefined as Object.success"